# Exoplayer Downloading Media, DefaultHTTPDataSource is crashing the app

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, exoplayer-media-item

I'm using DownloadService from Exoplayer to download HLS videos. https://exoplayer.dev/downloading-media.html

The links I'm supplying are pre-authorized links for downloading HLS videos. Sometimes I'm seeing an app crash on 401. Stack below:

```
Exception com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 401
  at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open (SourceFile:47)
  at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open (SourceFile:21)
  at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open (SourceFile:3)
  at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.checkOpened (SourceFile:2)
  at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.open
  at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.ParsingLoadable.load (SourceFile:9)
  at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run (SourceFile:6)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
```

I tried to reproduce this by giving expired links. The exoplayer downloader is handling it gracefully. I'm confused now where to look ? What could be the possible reason ?

Here's the implemenatation for DownloadManager, where I'm giving Executor and DataSource:

```kotlin
private fun getManager(     context: Context,     databaseProvider: ExoDatabaseProvider,     simpleCache: SimpleCache,     downloadListener: OPDownloadListener,     threadPoolSize: Int ): DownloadManager {     val manager = DownloadManager(         context,         DefaultDownloadIndex(databaseProvider),         DefaultDownloaderFactory(             CacheDataSource.Factory()                 .setCache(simpleCache)                 .setCacheKeyFactory(OPDownloadCacheKeyFactory())                 .setUpstreamDataSourceFactory(getHttpDataSourceFactory(context)),             Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadPoolSize)         )     )     manager.addListener(downloadListener)     manager.maxParallelDownloads = MAX_PARALLEL_DOWNLOADS     return manager
```

I was not expecting the crash, and if it is, it should happen every time.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. This is happening during playback. If you supply an expired link to exoplayer playback, following error stack comes:

```
     Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 401
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:382)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:258)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:84)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.checkOpened(DataSourceInputStream.java:99)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.open(DataSourceInputStream.java:62)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.ParsingLoadable.load(ParsingLoadable.java:174)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:409)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
```